# Beginner needing experienced advice for important choices

Tags: python

I've never written a program, (although I've dabbled in Access and am familiar with OOP concepts), and have decided to undertake the challenge of writing myself a database program for home use.  (It'll keep track of our finances and be customized to our way of doing things.)  I've pretty much decided to use Python and SQLite, but that still leaves other decisions to be made.  I think I should get experienced advice and help choosing because I know nothing about the pros and cons (for my situation) of what's out there.

I know I'll need reports of some kind (something similar to Access reports would be ideal).  Also I'll need (the easiest way) to build a UI.  What are some softwares that I (total beginner) should look at for those purposes?  And are there other tools will I need besides those?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Update.** Are there any drag and drop form and report development tools for Python/Sqlite (similar to Access)?  What about opinions on Netbeans IDE and Swing UI for me?

Comment: When you say you've never written a program, do you mean not even "Hello World"?

Comment: Not exactly.  In class we wrote very basic C++ console programs.  And I've done some VBA coding in Access.  But, never anything in Python, or with a UI (except Access's UI), or stand-alone from scratch, and outside classroom conditions and guidance (except the Access stuff).

Answer (score 5):

Tkinter is a *great** UI framework for beginners. I highly recommend using that, if it seems powerful enough to fill your needs.

Since it sounds like you're pretty inexperienced as far as programming goes, here's what I recommend:

1) Learn how to do basic IO, and especially learn Python's string formatting. It's super useful, and probably invaluable in your situation.

2) Learn how to do SQL queries with SQLite - attach your Python IO skills to SQLite.

3) Learn Python's object model - how it fits within the concept of OOP, and especially how you can make an object to fit your data model. Learn how this can work in between Python's IO and SQLite IO.

4) Now that you're comfortable putting data into and getting data out of a SQLite database and a user, and can handle objects comfortably, it's time to start learning about event driven programming, mainloops, and GUI layouts. Tkinter is pretty simple and [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) has some rather good information about Tkinter.

5) Tie all of these skills and knowledge together and make yourself a program. You'll probably have to go back and brush up, relearn, or learn some new things about 1-4 all along the way. Don't be afraid to re-factor code - if it seems like something is a pain to work with/around, you're probably doing *something* wrong, or just not seeing a solution right in front of your face. In some cases it's ignorance, in others you've just been looking at your program too long and may be married to the idea of doing it the "wrong" way. If your solution isn't simple, then you may be complicating the problem.

6) Ask for help. If you get stuck, you can always ask here, or at the [python tutor mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) . Just tell/show what you've done, what you expect to happen, and what it does instead. Most pythonistas tend to be a rather helpful bunch, and even more so when you show you've been trying to work at it yourself.

Anyhow, HTH, and good programming!

*by great I mean it has good features, but it's not very pretty or overly complicated. Plus it comes standard with your Python install.

For instance, a simple tkinter program with a label and a button could look like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
# Initialize a new root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a label that belongs to the root window
hello = tk.Label(root, text='Hello')

# Create a button that belongs to root, and will make the program 
# quit when pressed
goodbye = tk.Button(root, text='Goodbye', command=root.quit)

# Use the pack manager to add the button and label to the root
# Window - do NOT mix pack and grid managers - they don't play well
hello.pack()
goodbye.pack()

# Enter the mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the great info.  Is Tkinter done from command line or is there an IDE/visual designer you would recommend for me?  I'm looking for the easiest route from start to functional program.

Comment: I've always done it from the command line. It's fairly simple to make a program. I'll add a short sample program to my answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

One advice if you've never done any programming before is: small steps.

Write a small program that extracts things from a SQLite database and just prints them. Learn how that works and throw it away.
Do the same with reading files, make a simple GUI and so on with all the aspects you need to know for your program.

Once you know the pieces, try putting them together.

Comment: Writing super small example programs is the way I like to learn. Write something super small: "hey, I can connect to SQLlite", "Hey, I can do a query!". "Hey, I can get input from the user". Then build a bigger program from there.